# Basic Implementation Of jPlayer In A Ruby On Rails Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jplayer

I just started an online course for JavaScript.  The only jQuery code I have used is from Bootstrap.  I am a newbie indeed.

This is my first time attempting to use jPlayer.  I have downloaded the zip file on my Mac Computer.  I have copied jquery.jplayer.min.js into /assets/javascripts.  I have the following code into my view.  I used code that I saw on another solution where the person attempted to implement the circle player.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function()
            {
        var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
        {
            mp3: "MyMP3File.mp3"
        }, {
                supplied: "mp3",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
                swfPath: "js",
                wmode: "window"
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have recompiled the assets.  However no player displays on my view.  My mp3 file is in the public folder.  My guess is that it is ignoring the script file I added or else I need to copy more files.

I thought that maybe I needed to add a require statement for jPlayer in application.js. I cannot find anything that states the steps needed to implement jPlayer in Ruby on Rails.  I find solutions after implementation where just some script code is included.

Any help would be appreciated.  I will continue searching.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following line to your javascript manifest (application.js or vendor.js if you keep your assets separate), otherwise the file will not be compiled and made available for use:

```
//= require jquery.jplayer.min
```

Once you add the above, you'll be in business to use the code above (assuming it is correct). I strongly suggest checking out the [Rails Asset Pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).